# Redshift data access from node jdbc

Tags: node.js, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am getting below error when I try to data from redshift with the below mentioned code

```
var jdbc = new ( require('jdbc') );
var config = {
  libpath: 'C:/Users/ABCD/Desktop/jar/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.6.1006.jar',
  //libs: [__dirname + 'path/to/other/jars.jar'],
  drivername: 'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver',
  url: 'jdbc:redshift://examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx'
};

jdbc.initialize(config, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

var genericQueryHandler = function(err, results) { 
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } else if (results) {
      console.log(results);
}

jdbc.close(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connection closed successfully!");
  }
});
};

jdbc.open(function(err, conn) {
if (conn) {
     // SELECT statements are called with executeQuery 
     jdbc.executeQuery("select * from information_schema.tables", genericQueryHandler);
}
});
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\ABCD> node redshift.js
C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\jdbc.js:62> 
if(this._props.getPropertySync('user') === undefined){> 
  ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function

at JDBCConn.initialize
(C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\jdbc.js:62:20)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\AngularJS\redshift.js:15:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Could you please let me know whether there is nay issue with the above mentioned node jdbc usage for redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please be aware that this answer applies to node-jdbc 0.0.15 and earlier only.  It will not work for node-jdbc 0.1.1 or later, as the API has been completely reworked and is not backwards-compatible.**

Try replacing the two lines in your configuration

```
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx'
```

with

```
  properties: [
    ['user', 'xxxx'],
    ['password', 'xxxxx']
  ]
```

I got the same error as you attempting to use Node to connect to a local Oracle XE database.  After making the change above I was able to connect.  I don't believe the error you are getting is specific to RedShift - I believe it affects all databases.

Note that the properties above have to be specified as an array of 2-element arrays.  An object such as the following would seem the obvious way to specify the properties, but it doesn't work:

```
  // Don't do this, it doesn't work.
  properties: {
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx'
  }
```

To be honest, the fix I've proposed above is a workaround.  I only found it by reading the source of the jdbc module.  I can't say I'm terribly impressed with this module, what with the example code given in the documentation not working, and with a somewhat counter-intuitive and undocumented format for specifying custom properties.

Comment: Thanks alot Luke , it worked perfectly.
I am also looking different options to connect to redshift from nodejs.
I have found below but none of them are helpful
https://github.com/NextUserSF/node-redshift
https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm