# Redshift data access from node jdbc throwing errors

Tags: node.js, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am getting below error when I try to data from redshift with the below mentioned code: I feel that it is due to `jdbc module` not installed correctly.Could

/*
 * **GET users listing**.
 */

```
var jdbc =require('jdbc');
var express = require('express');

var config = {
        libpath: '../RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.6.1006.jar',
        drivername: 'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver',
        url: 'jdbc:redshift://exampleCluster.abcdkcmf0ug1.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/xyz',
        properties: [
            ['user', 'XXXXX'],
            ['password', 'XXXXXX']
        ]
    };

console.log(config);
var hsqldb=new jdbc(config);

hsqldb.status();
hsqldb.initialize(config, function(err, res) {

    console.log("Connection opened successfully!");


    if (err) {
console.log("Error during Initializing");
        console.log(err);
    }

});


exports.list = function(req, res){


    hsqldb.open(function(err, conn) {
         if (conn) {
        // SELECT statements are called with executeQuery 
             hsqldb.executeQuery("select * from schema.table", function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                } else if (results) {
                  console.log(results);
                  res.type('text/plain');           // set content-type
                  res.send(results);    
                }

            hsqldb.close(function(err) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log("Connection closed successfully!");
                }
                });

                }
);
         }
        });
 // res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

**Error:**

> C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:97
>       return callback(null);
>              ^
>   TypeError: object is not a function
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:97:12
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:363:13
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
>       at done (C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:243:17)
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:360:17
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:90:7
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:28:14
>       at C:\Users\ABCD\node_modules\jdbc\lib\drivermanager.js:26:18

Similar Post: [Redshift data access from node jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001900/redshift-data-access-from-node-jdbc)

Could Some one please let me know what went wrong here.Is it some thing wrong with the code? or is it with the modules not installed correctly. I feel it is due to modules not installed correctly since I saw few errors while installing the jdbc module.

Please let me know the steps to be taken to install jdbc module in node js.

Answer (score 0):

The node-jdbc API has been completely reworked since version 0.1.1 was released, so any old documentation relating to older versions of node-jdbc, including my answer to the question linked above, is no longer helpful.

Using node-jdbc 0.1.1, the code to connect to your database should look something like the following:

```
var jdbc = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['../RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.6.1006.jar']);
}

var config = {
    drivername: 'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver',
    url: 'jdbc:redshift://exampleCluster.abcdkcmf0ug1.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/xyz',
    properties: {
        "user": "XXXXX",
        "password": "XXXXX"
    }
};

var hsqldb=new JDBC(config);

hsqldb.status();
hsqldb.initialize(function(err, res) {
    /* ... */
});
```

In particular:

- The classpath is now configured in a `jinst` object and has moved out of the configuration.
- `properties` is now an object, not an array of 2-element arrays as it was in version 0.0.15.
- The `initialize` method now takes only one parameter, the callback.  It no longer takes the configuration as a parameter as that was provided in the constructor.
- node-jdbc supposedly supports specifying the `user` and `password` properties in the `config` object, which avoids using `properties` for this.  However, I would recommend avoiding this as it does not work.  If you try it, you may well get errors about the username and password not being valid, even if you've typed them in correctly.

The reason you are getting the somewhat unintelligible error is because you were passing the configuration object to the `initialize` method, which was expecting only a callback.  The error doesn't get noticed until Node tries to 'call' the configuration object as if it were a function, which of course fails.